# NSFetchedResultsController cache mismatch again

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, exception, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is another case where calling `performFetch` on an `NSFetchedResultController` breaks with an exception saying:

> FATAL ERROR: The persistent cache of section information does not match the current configuration.  You have illegally mutated the NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request, its predicate, or its sort descriptor without either disabling caching or using +deleteCacheWithName:

Except I haven't done any of this. To understand the problem, look at the predicate:

> predicate: (collection.identifier == ";root" AND doc.status == 0);

Now look at the mismatched cache contents:

```
cached objects were: (
  "MyDocument 'PL00002.jpeg' in set '/' (#2147483647)",
  "MyDocument 'PL00003.jpeg' in set '/' (#2147483647)",
  "MyDocument 'PL00003.pdf' in set '/' (#2147483647)",
  "MyDocument 'PL00002.pdf' in set '/' (#2147483647)"
)
fetched objects are: (
  "MyDocument 'PL00002.jpeg' in set '/' (#2147483647)",
  "MyDocument 'PL00003.jpeg' in set '/' (#2147483647)",
  "MyDocument 'PL00004.jpeg' in set '/' (#2147483647)",
  "MyDocument 'PL00003.pdf' in set '/' (#2147483647)",
  "MyDocument 'PL00002.pdf' in set '/' (#2147483647)",
  "MyDocument 'PL00004.pdf' in set '/' (#2147483647)"
)
```

Indeed, there are two new matching objects. The reasons is that the two new objects (`PL00004.jpeg` and `PL00004.pdf`) had previously their `status` property to a value <>0 and I changed their `status` back to 0 in code because they started to satisfy some external condition (not triggered by a user action).

For completeness, here is the code that triggers the exception:

```
- (void) reloadData
{
  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    abort(); // I have actually better error handling
  }       
  [_gridView reloadData];
}
```

also note:

- no other `NSFetchedResultController` uses a cache with the same name
- `_gridView` is not a `UITableView`, though it also displays a collection of entities. This detail should not be relevant.
- none of the `NSFetchedResultController` delegate methods are ever called, esp not when I change the status of my two objects to 0
- everything runs OK if I empty the cache before `performFetch:` (or with no caching).
- I call this `reloadData` method on my controller at the end of my periodical check for that external condition I mentioned above.
- The `NSFetchedResultController` is created with an *`nil`* `sectionNameKeyPath`.
- As explained I never change `fetchedResultsController`: not its predicate, not its fetch request, not its sort order, nothing.

I don't think I should get this exception simply because new objects now satisfy the predicate. Deleting the cache avoids the exception, but as long as I don't understand why I should do that, I don't consider that as a *fix*.

Any idea what I miss here?

Edit: here is the requested information:

The code to set up the `NSFetchedResultController`. When the user chooses a collection, this is called:

```
- (void) displayCollection:(Collection *)aSet
{
    self.currentCollection = aSet;      
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchRequest];
    NSString *collectionIdentifier = @";root"; // no selection is like "select root collection";
    if (aSet) {
        collectionIdentifier = aSet.identifier;
    }
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"collection.identifier == %@ and doc.status == %d", collectionIdentifier, upToDate];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:cacheName];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        abort(); // whatever
    }       
    [_gridView reloadData];
}
```

`fetchedResultsController` was initialized thus:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DocInCollection" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"collection.identifier == %@ and doc.status == %d", @";root", upToDate];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:cacheName];
```

The code that is called when `doc.status` is updated:

```
- (void) setUpToDate
{
  self.status = [NSNumber numberWithInt:upToDate];
  NSError *error = nil;
  [[self managedObjectContext] save:&error];
  if (error) { } // whatever
  [[self managedObjectContext] processPendingChanges];
}
```

`cacheName` is a global const `NSString`, `upToDate` is an enum constant (0).

Finally the model is a bit complex because of other entities that are used by the application. Here is a simplified version:

[model http://emberapp.com/jdmuys/images/untitled-1/sizes/m.png](http://emberapp.com/jdmuys/images/untitled-1/sizes/m.png)

Comment: You should post the code where (1) you configure your fetched results controller and (2) where you change the objects. The problem must be in one of those two places.

Comment: A sketch of your data model would be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your `sectionNameKeyPath` and it's relationship, if any, to the attribute being mutated. It would seem from the error message that your sections are changing in a way the controller does not like.

Not sure if it is related at all but I would be nervous of any statement that has an unescaped semicolon in it. That predicate bit of `";root"` gives me an itch. Of course, any problems with it should show up at compile time but still...

### Update:

Out of morbid curiosity I banged together a test data model and some code using the above. The following will not even compile:

```
NSManagedObject *cMO=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Collection" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
NSManagedObject *dMO=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Doc" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
[cMO setValue:@";root" forKey:@"identifier"];
[dMO setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"status"];
[cMO setValue:dMO forKey:@"doc"];
NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Collection" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc]];
NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier==";root" AND doc.status==0"];
[fetch setPredicate:p];
NSArray *a=[self performFetch:fetch];
NSLog(@"%@",a);
```

Changing the predicate to:

```
NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == ';root' AND doc.status == 0"];
```

... compiles and works properly. I suggest you change the `";root"` to `';root'` at least for troubleshooting.

Comment: my `sectionNameKeyPath` is `nil`. `";root"` is just the *value* of the root collection identifier (my collections are organized hierarchically). This is normal and unrelated. This semi-colon has nothing to do with the statement-termination character in C-based languages and has its historical roots in the separation character in pseudo-csv files.

Comment: See my updated answer. The predicate as written in the parent will not compile under Xcode4 and iOS4.2.

Comment: Sigh. I wasn't clear enough. The predicate is not the problem. I even didn't show the source code to create it. To clarify, I will edit my question to show that source code.